# VLOOKUP first 5 characters

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I know there have been many questions regarding this and I did read through these (+ the answers). But the formula suggested in each of them does not seem to work for me.

I have created [a sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1km_OKKkEkbdfp1ghrgnLjrO03OXOx9ONjGyMGf0rX-Y/edit?usp=sharing) for other people to look at, so that you all understand what I have been trying to do. I basically want my VLookup to search for the first 5 characters, but it's giving me an error. I used the formula that was suggested here in some other threads, but it doesn't seem to give any results.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It'd be useful to the post if you added what you've tried.

Comment: @SeanR It's in the sheet. Where the error shows.

Comment: @A.Be Please put everything in the question as plain text.

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/)(NOT as IMAGE) to the question. Adding such [md tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left()`, like this:

`=arrayformula( if( len(A2:A); iferror( vlookup( left(A2:A; 5) & "*"; F2:G; columns(F2:G); false) ); iferror(1/0) ) )`

This array formula will automatically fill the whole column.

To do the same with a fill-down formula, remove the `arrayformula()` wrapper and use a row absolute reference, like this:

`=vlookup( left(A2; 5) & "*"; F$2:G; columns(F$2:G); false)`

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1km_OKKkEkbdfp1ghrgnLjrO03OXOx9ONjGyMGf0rX-Y/edit#gid=966747204) for an illustration.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Very interesting solution. Can you explain why we need an array formula while all sources online suggest the solution I had previously tried but gave me an error?

Comment: You do not need an array formula. It just makes spreadsheet maintenance easier. Edited the answer to show how to do the same with a fill-down formula.

Answer (score 0):

try in C2:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="";;IFNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2:A; 5)&"*"; F2:G12; 2; ))))
```

[image]